# troubleshooting job submission on slurm: Not a directory

Tags: r, slurm, hpc

While submitting a Rscript job on slurm I get the following error.

```
slurmstepd: error: execve(): /var/spool/slurmd/job655284/slurm_script: Not a directory
```

my submission script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash/
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --partition=xlong
#SBATCH --qos=4node_qos
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=120:00:00

module load R/4.2.2

Rscript try.R
```

The R script is simple with loop running in multiple directories to read files and project crs.
The R script runs perfectly on interactive mode.

Any suggestions on where I could be missing.

Comment: That error is listed here https://portal.supercomputing.wales/index.php/index/slurm/slurm-faq/ and at least from that page seems to imply it's occurring after your jobs has completed. Do you get any output from your job? You probably want to contact whomever administers your computing cluster. This doesn't seem to be R related necessarily.

Comment: Oh. Nevermind. That error is also here https://hackmd.io/@AaltoSciComp/ArchiveSummer20210609 and points out the first line should be `#!/bin/bash` (without the slash at the end) So that's probably the real issue